# What are other ASP.NET web applications that are as well done as StackOverflow?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

It's my understanding that StackOverflow (SO) was built using ASP.NET.  What surprised me is it's so well designed and well implemented. Without knowing much about the internals of SO, here are my observations and educated guesses:

1. SO appears to be highly scalable.
2. URLs in SO are friendly.
3. It appears that SO does not contain a bunch of controls as most ASP.NET apps I've seen.
4. Judiciously and effectively use of Ajax requests, opacity animation, etc.  Viewing source tells me SO is using jQuery.
5. SO runs on all major browsers (that I've used and this list includes IE, FF, Chrome, Opera).

Edit: 6. Comet-like feature: As you type your answer, if there is any other answer posted, you get the notification.  If you choose to load it, of course only a partial page refresh is done and your answer remain intact.  Have yet to see this in any other ASP.NET app.

So my questions:

- What are other ASP.NET web
  applications that are as well done
  as StackOverflow and what are their
  features that you like?
- Can you share
  about some more details about SO,
  for example is SO built using
  ASP.NET MVC or something else?

Comment: Yeah, I am really liking the site's design. I am looking to update my site with better URLs and user interface in general.

Comment: Wow I'm impressed. My impression of ASP.NET is that it creates really crappy web sites, even though I'm a .NET programmer. Kudos to the site designers for disproving me. :)

Comment: Removed the argumentative and inflammatory remarks irrelevant to the core question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orkut.com - A social networking site by google uses ASP.NET

Answer (score 8):

SO is built using ASP.NET MVC as explained by Jeff Atwood and his team [in this podcast organised by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=152)

Listening to the podcast would be worthwhile.

One surprising element about SO which was revealed in the podcast is that **SO runs on a single server (IIS & SQL Server)**. I was surprised by this.

Comment: They now have a separate sql box. Phil Haacks pdc video with Jeff is a good watch

Answer (score 6):

ASP.NET Forms allows developers to build UIs in much the same way as .NET Windows Forms.

The whole idea was that a developer that knew how to build a 'Fat Client' Windows form could transfer those skills to ASP.NET forms.  ASP.NET forms even allowed developers to pretty much put code on the same set of control events.  The developer was sheilded from having to have any knowledge of HTML, HTTP, Javascript etc.

Unfortunately this resulted in large POSTs containing monster viewstate being generated frequently and hence a poor user experience.  This is what has given ASP.NET a bad rep.  In reality its the original ASP.NET **Forms** that should have the bad rep.

ASP.NET MVC, amoungst other things, embraces the nature of HTTP rather than trying to hide it.  AJAX and JQuery are also features of MVC which add to the overall result being better.

That said having a great tool is useless without great vision, design and skill, the SO team clearly have those in abundance.

Comment: I've used so many poor ASP.NET apps and you clearly explained why. That's why I'm so surprised to find out about SO, which is unlike anything I've seen before (in ASP world). You also convince me with your explanation about how MVC embraces HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

SO was build with ASP.NET MVC. Jeff hired good developers, had a good vision, and ran his screens through a real designer.

Answer (score 1):

Myspace.com uses ASP.net, which proves the scalability of the platform in general. You can also learn a lot about stackoverflow itself from reading the [stackoverflow blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com) and listening to the stackoverflow podcasts.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the things you point out about are actually due to the use of ASP.NET MVC. Pretty URLs come out of the box, non-standard controls, well nothing comes out of the box with MVC so you have to reinvent everything :), and finally the AJAX is pretty much a requirement for ASP.NET MVC if you want to do anything intelligent with it.

ASP.NET MVC alone does not account for the things which makes StackOverflow truly successful that's all down to the idea, execution, and the fact that Jeff and Joel combined garners a huge following on the net.

Comment: But this was part of my question: Is it built with MVC? But this is not the essence of the question.  The essence is what are other apps that are like SO? I wasn't clear, but I want to find out other impressive ASP.NET and ASP.NET MBC apps?

Ajax is a requirement for ASP.NET MVC? A requirement?

Comment: While not an aboslute requirement, AJAX completes the MVC story, so you'd be hard pressed to find an MVC application which doesn't use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can also learn quite a lot about the development, planning(!), etc in the two HanselMinutes podcasts on SO:

- [StackOverflow uses ASP.NET MVC - Jeff Atwood and his technical team](http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=152)
- [Behind the Scenes - StackOverflow and Jeff Atwood - Part 2](http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=153)

Available in numerous audio formats, as well as transcribed.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET creates websites limited only by the talent of the developers.

The same can be said for virtually any framework.

That said, Windows Server/IIS/.NET is a hugely scalable concept, as we serve far far more traffic than SO on a ASP.NET site (Then again, we have 32 servers).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of the answers here, myspace.com uses ASP.NET (as far as I know it was written in ColdFusion and used BlueDragon for .NET).

One other site is plentyoffish.com (60M hits per day).

If you want to read more about scalability see http://highscalability.com